# Prevent form splitting onto second CSS3 column

Tags: html, forms, css

I have 2 columns that I have defined in CSS:

```
.two-columns
{
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count:2;
     column-count:2;
}
```

and multiple forms. Unfortunately, some of my forms are split into two; half on the left column and half on the right column. How can I prevent this from happening? I've tried using `<fieldset>` but that won't work. Using `<br />` would work but its not ideal because my pages are created dynamically and some of the forms could dynamically change in size.

**Edit**

I now have it working with `fieldsets` by applying this line of CSS `display:inline-block;` Unfortunately, I can still not make it work on forms that don't have `fieldsets`.

```
<div class="wrapper two-columns">
    <form action="change-width" method="post">
        <h2>Width</h2>
        <input type="number" name="width" min="50" max="9999" value="1000" placeholder="Width" required />&nbsp;Width of Page<br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="change-width" value="wrappers" checked="checked" />Wrappers</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="change-width" value="box" />Box</label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Change" />
        <p id="change-width-status"></p>
    </form>
    <form action="change-fieldset" method="post">
        <h2>Fieldset</h2>
        <label><input type="radio" name="change-fieldset" value="fieldset" />Fieldset</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="change-fieldset" value="h2" checked="checked" />&lt;h2&gt;</label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Change" />
        <p id="change-fieldset-status"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have a few forms but they are formated the same way so I've left them out.

**Edit**

I have it working now by using `display:inline-block;` and adding a `<br />` after every `form`. A pure CSS solution would be better but it doesn't look like there is one.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? [`display: inline-block;` works fine on the  `form` in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/xwnt30bn/) (with block inputs)

Comment: Please share your snippet or create a fiddle.

Comment: I've added some of my HTML code at the bottom of my question.

Comment: With the (pathetic) lack of implementation of any [`break-inside` CSS property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), it seems you are better off wrapping multiple forms in a div with `display: inline-block` [like this example](https://jsfiddle.net/pm6bpe5o/). Not ideal, but it works cross-browser.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that tomoz but now I must sleep coz it's nearly 5am. I would prefer to do this in pure CSS ideally though.

Comment: I have it working now by using `display:inline-block;` and adding `<br />` after every `form`.